# Criptografia em C

Tags: c, arquivo, segurança, criptografia, ascii

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C, que será capaz de criptografar e descriptografar textos e salvá-los em disco separadamente.

Quero utilizar a tabela ASCII para a implementação da Criptografia, estou conseguindo criptografar mas na hora de reverter o texto estou tendo grandes dificuldades, o programa salva apenas um caractere "aleatório" ao invés de salvar o texto que fora digitado antes de ser criptografado.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Criptografar(char chave[])
{
    int tam_chave = strlen(chave);    //Configuração da chave para criptografia
    char texto[100000];               //Vetor de entrada de texto a ser criptografado
    int texto_cript[100000];          //Vetor de encriptação
    int valor_chave, aux = 0, i;      //Variáveis de controle de chave

    FILE *arquivo;                    //ponteiro do arquivo

    printf("\n\nDigite o texto a ser criptografado: \n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]s", texto);        //Lê o que você digitar
    printf("\n\n");                   //Separa pra não virar bagunça

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++)
    {
        texto_cript[i]=texto[i];      //Atribui pro TEXTO_CRIPT o ASCII dos caracteres digitados
    }
    while(aux < strlen(texto))        //Vai de 0 até o tamanho do texto incrementando dentro do for
    {
        for(i = 0; i < tam_chave; i++)//Percorre a chave dinâmicamente ex.: "aBcd" 0123
        {
            valor_chave = chave[i];   //pega o ASCII da chave dinâmicamente ex.: "a" = 65
            texto_cript[aux] *= valor_chave; //multiplica o ASCII de TEXTO_CRIPT pelo ASCII de VALOR_CHAVE e atribui para TEXTO_CRIPT.
                                             //EX.: "a" 65 * 65 = 4225
            aux++;                           //incrementa o AUX
        }
    }

    arquivo = fopen("criptografado.txt", "w"); //Cria o arquivo pra escrita
    if (arquivo==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nErro ao criar o arquivo.....\n\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(texto); i++)//percorre o texto digitado pelo usuário
        {
            fprintf(arquivo, "%d", texto_cript[i]); //grava em arquivo o texto já encriptado
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);    //fecha o arquivo
}

int Descriptografar(char chave[])
{
    int tam_chave = strlen(chave);      //Configuração da chave para criptografia
    int texto_decript[100000];          //Vetor de descriptação
    int valor, pos_chave = 0, pos_texto  = 0, i; //Variáveis de controle de chave

    FILE *arquivo;

    arquivo = fopen("criptografado.txt", "r"); //Abre o arquivo para leitura
    if (arquivo==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nErro ao criar o arquivo.....\n\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
       while(!feof(arquivo))    //Percorre o arquivo criptografado até o final
       {
           fscanf(arquivo,"%d", &valor);    //Lê os valores criptografados em ASCII
           valor /= chave[pos_chave];       //Divide o valor pelo ASCII da posição ASCII da chave
           texto_decript[pos_texto] = (char)valor; //TEXTO_DECRIPT recebe o typecasting de valor, ex.: 65 = "a"
           pos_texto++;                     //incrementa a posição do vetor TEXTO_DECRIPT

           if (pos_chave == tam_chave-1) //Percorre a chave e retorna na posição inicial
           {
               pos_chave = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               pos_chave++;             //Senão, incrementa a chave
           }
       }
    }
    fclose(arquivo); //Fecha o aarquivo com o texto criptografado

    arquivo = fopen("descriptografado.txt", "w"); //Cria um novo arquivo para escrita
    fprintf(arquivo, "%s", texto_decript);        //Grava em arquivo o texto já decriptado
    printf("\n\nO arquivo foi descriptado com sucesso!\n\n\n"); //Frescura minha pra dizer que terminou a função
}

int main(void)
{
    int opcao = 0;
    do
    {
        //MENU
        printf("\nSelecione uma opcao:\n 1 - Criptografar texto digitado.\n 2 - Descriptografar texto.\n 3 - Sair.\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        switch(opcao)
        {
            case 1:
                Criptografar("AbCd"); //Ativa a função passando como parâmetro a chave desejada
                break;
            case 2:
                Descriptografar("AbCd"); //Faz a mesma coisa que eu comentei acima
                break;
            case 3:
                continue;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcao invalida! Tente Novamente.\n\n");
        }
    }while(opcao != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas no seu código.

O primeiro é o transbordamento. Um `signed int` (ou simplesmente `int`) armazena valores entre  -2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647. Agora veja o que acontece se o usuário quizer criptografar a letra z:

```
for(i = 0; i < tam_chave; i++)
{
    valor_chave = chave[i];
    texto_cript[aux] *= valor_chave;
    aux++;                       
}
```

Considerando que a chave é "AbCd". texto[aux] vai ser igual a 122 * 65 * 98 * 67 * 100, que é igual a 5206838000. Você poderia até remediar declarando o vetor `texto_cript` como do tipo `unsigned int`, mas no fim seria quase a mesma coisa.

O outro problema é a forma como você está lendo e gravando os dados. Os números estão sendo gravados em formato de texto, um após o outro, sem dar chance de determinar por onde começa ou termina o número correspondente a ao caractere criptografado.